# I can't use ASP.NET Identity and JWT autentication at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing a platform with ASP.NET Core 5 that uses Identity as a membership system. Aside from the web application, this platform also exposes a Web API. I have tried using JWT as Web API authentication. But when I add the JWT configuration I'm no longer able to login to the web application.

This is the `Startup.cs` file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    private MappingProfile mappingProfile;

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>() //Line that can help you
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        // JWT
        // If it is commented, I can login to the web app, if not I can't
        /*services
            //.AddHttpContextAccessor()
            //.AddAuthorization()
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });*/

        // AUTOMAPPER
        this.mappingProfile = new MappingProfile();
        MapperConfiguration mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc => {
            mc.AddProfile(this.mappingProfile);
        });
        IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddSignalR();

        // REPOSITORIES
        services.AddScoped<IExampleRepository, ExampleRepository>();
        
        // LOCALIZATION
        services.AddLocalization(/*options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"*/);
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("es")
            };
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext context, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager, IStringLocalizer<MappingProfile> mappingProfileLocalizer)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "areas",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<DcHub>("/dchub");
        });

        this.mappingProfile.Localizer = mappingProfileLocalizer;
        ApplicationDbInitializer.Initialize(context, roleManager);
    }
}
```

I think that I'm missing something in this configuration.

In case it can be of help, information about the development environment and libraries:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 (Version 16.11.15)
- .NET 5

Comment: Providing error messages can help resolve the problem.

Comment: There is no error. I just try to login to the web, in the code I see that the code is executed correctly, but when redirecting to the index page, the session is not logged in.

Comment: I did a test in my side and I also found that when I add jwt authentication, then I can't sign in the app. I think you may follow [this document](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-authentication-and-authorization-in-net-6-0-with-identity-framework/) to change your application, follow this document I can make it work.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using .NET 5 because I don't have VS2022 license. I tried with another tutorial from the same author with .NET 5 and Swagger with the same result: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-5-with-jwt-and-swagger/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the documentation about using multiple schemens ([Authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-5.0)) and writing some changes in authentication configuration, I found how to solve the problem.

In `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method I configure cookie and JWT bearer authentication schemes:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication() // Cookie by default
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Unauthorized/";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Forbidden/";
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });
```

With this all controller actions and pages that have `[Authorize]` attribute will use cookie scheme. In Web API controllers you have to specify JWT bearer scheme in the attribute:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

**One note.** Using the attribute in this way doesn't work:

```
[Authorize(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```